# Classical Guitar: How to play slur followed by a chord

Tags: classical-guitar

How to play the notes in the image? Is it play the third string with slur for the second string at the same time?

[image: score snapshot]

Answer (score 10):

This slur is only on the second string, with the "p" denoting a "pull off" from 1st fret of second string.
So yes, you need to do a "pull off" on the second string, while plucking the third open string.

Answer (score 6):

Play the low E, then the C on 2nd string, 1st fret. *Then*, as you play the 3rd string open, you carefully pull off from 1st fret to open, 2nd string. The slur denotes legato, and the 'p' denotes how the writer wants that played legato. There are other ways to play legato, so he's being specific.

Comment: So you don't pluck the G on the third string along with the C on the second string.  You play the C on the upbeat first then pull-off to B and pluck the G both on the downbeat.

Comment: @mrbean - no, of course you don't. Otherwise the G would be written under the C note - which it's not. Music dots are read rather like written words, left to right, and played in that same order.